# Web Chat cards alignment

Tags: botframework

Me again with some WebChat questions..

So i'm using the hero cards, and they just doesn't looks good..
There is any way to fix their alignment? 
[image]

Thanks!

Comment: [This repo](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/issues/new) is probably the right place to ask this one.